# C# .NET Core, function taking a list of tuple values with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, tuples

I've been reading around and can't seem to find a way to allow a function to take a generic tuple at all but also haven't found anywhere that says a Tuple can't take generic parameters, is this at all possible in C#? Below is the type of function I want to define (obviously doesn't work).

```
public static TController CreateControllerWithAuthenticatedContextsAndResponseMessages<TController>(
        List<Tuple<TRequest, TResponse, Func<TResponse>, Expression<Func<TRequest, bool>>>> genList, 
        string policyName)
        where TController : class
        where TRequest : class
        where TResponse : class
    {

    }
```

Is this possible to do at all? Otherwise is there another way to take these parameters? The reason it's this complicated is because I want to make sure the user (us) can't pass the wrong number of each parameter as it needs one of each.

EDIT: sorry, should've been clearer. TRequest and TResponse need to be lists of generics because they'll be something like AddedThis, AddedThat. With result functions and expressions to match. This is for mocking a controller for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does work, but you have to define all the generic type parameters in the method's signature:

```
public static TController CreateControllerWithAuthenticatedContextsAndResponseMessages
    <TController, TRequest, TResponse>
( ... )
```

Numbers 2 and 3 were missing.

Comment: Ah sorry, should've been clearer - TRequest and TResponse will be different classes, eg. TRequests could be AddThis and AddThat, making the repsonses AddedThis, AddedThat and will need functions and expressions of each matching

Comment: @JamesMorrison All generic type parameters must be declared after the function name anyway. What they will be or to what constraints they will be bound is irrelevant. This is language syntax requirement

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius oh yeah of course! I think I've had to twist my brain beyond logical thinking to get to having to declare this type of function in the first place!